# How to populate arrays with values read in from csv via pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have create a `DataFrame` using `pandas` by reading a csv file. What I want to do is iterate down the rows (for the values in column 1) into a certain array, and do the same for the values in column 2 for a different array. This seems like it would normally be a fairly easy thing to do, so I think I am missing something, however I can't find much online that doesn't get too complicated and doesn't seem to do what I want. Stack questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42357180/how-to-populate-array-with-multiple-rows-from-csv-file-using-python-pandas) *appear* to be asking the same thing, but the answers are long and complicated. Is there no way to do this in a few lines of code? Here is what I have set up:

```
import pandas as pd 

#available possible players
playerNames = []

df = pd.read_csv('Fantasy Week 1.csv')
```

What I anticipate I should be able to do would be something like:

```
for row in df.columns[1]:
    playerNames.append(row)
```

This however does not return the desired result.

Essentially, if df =
[1,2,3
 4,5,6
 7,8,9], I would want my array to be [1,4,7]

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```
for row in df[df.columns[1]]:
    playerNames.append(row)
```

Or even better:

```
print(df[df.columns[1]].tolist())
```

In this case you want the 1st column's values so do:

```
for row in df[df.columns[0]]:
    playerNames.append(row)
```

Or even better:

```
print(df[df.columns[0]].tolist())
```

Comment: thank you for the prompt response. I recognize that this does what I want, but can you give me a bit of a break down of what exactly is happening in `df[df.columns[1]]`?

Comment: @AlekPiasecki `df.columns` returns the columns of a dataframe, `df.columns[1]` returns the 2nd column name, then we want to get the data of the column so do: `df[df.columns[1]]`

Comment: @AlekPiasecki Edited my answer

Comment: can I grab multiple columns at a time? I want to assign the value from the current row, column 1 for a key of a dictionary and the value from the current row, column 2 for the value of that dictionary?